# After upgrading to Mountain Lion don't work Rails app (Heroku + Git)

Tags: ruby, macos, git, heroku, osx-lion

Today I upgraded from Snow Leopard to Mountain Lion and when I try to check my Rails app hosted on Heroku
`heroku open`
I will get this error message:

```
 !    Heroku client internal error.
 !    Search for help at: https://help.heroku.com
 !    Or report a bug at: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/new

    Error:       No such file or directory -  git --version  (Errno::ENOENT)
    Backtrace:   /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/heroku-2.30.4/lib/heroku/helpers.rb:105:in ``'
                 /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/heroku-2.30.4/lib/heroku/helpers.rb:105:in `has_git?'
                 /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/heroku-2.30.4/lib/heroku/helpers.rb:110:in `git'
                 /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/heroku-2.30.4/lib/heroku/command/base.rb:206:in `git_remotes'
                 /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/heroku-2.30.4/lib/heroku/command/base.rb:179:in `extract_app_in_dir'
                 /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/heroku-2.30.4/lib/heroku/command/base.rb:31:in `app'
                 /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/heroku-2.30.4/lib/heroku/command/apps.rb:269:in `open'
                 /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/heroku-2.30.4/lib/heroku/command.rb:193:in `run'
                 /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/heroku-2.30.4/lib/heroku/cli.rb:25:in `start'
                 /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/heroku-2.30.4/bin/heroku:16:in `<top (required)>'
                 /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/heroku:19:in `load'
                 /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/heroku:19:in `<main>'

    Command:     heroku open
    Plugins:     heroku-sql-console
    Version:     heroku-gem/2.30.4 (x86_64-darwin10.8.0) ruby/1.9.2
```

When I try to check the **git**:
`git status`
I'll get:

```
-bash: git: command not found
```

What happend? The upgrade to the new version of **OS X** remove **Git and Heroku**?

**EDIT:** Ok, so the problem about `git` solved the Hombrew installation. But then, when I run the app - `rails s`, I got:

```
Unable to load the EventMachine C extension; To use the pure-ruby reactor, require 'em/pure_ruby'
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': dlopen(/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0/lib/rubyeventmachine.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0/lib/rubyeventmachine.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0/lib/rubyeventmachine.bundle
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0/lib/eventmachine.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler.rb:122:in `require'
    from /Users/adam/rubydev/future_computers/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I also tried to add the mentioned gem in the statement - `gem "eventmachine"` - even if I don't use it in my app, but didn't help me. Still the same error message.

Could anyone help me, please, how to fix this issue?

Thanks you in advance

Comment: what happens if you type `which git` or `which heroku`?

Comment: `which git` => nothing, `which heroku` => `/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/heroku`

Comment: did you ever figure out the part with the unable to load EventMachine C extension?

Answer (score 0):

Go to [Link](https://brew.sh/) and install homebrew and run

```
$ brew install git
```

It seems `git` is missing and you need it. Something must have broken on the transition - you will probably need to install it again and potentially rvm + ruby - but because they are stored in your home directory you should be ok. Just incase:

```
$ rvm get stable
$ rvm install 1.9.3
```

If your rails and heroku gems are missing you might need to download those again too.

The error seems to have come from installing git in system directory and it getting overwritten when you upgraded - go for homebrew so you are safe and it doesnt happen again.

Comment: Thank you Oliver, I am trying it according to your advices. When I run `brew install wget`, I get `Warning: Xcode is not installed! Builds may fail! Error: No such file or directory - /usr/bin/cc` I cannot get over this issue.